# MVC ReadOnly textbox not working as expected with backspace and spacebar Keys

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my application, we have an MVC form with 40 -50 different controls (textbox, dropdown and Jquery date pickers). I need to set few textbox fields to read-only in edit mode and based on the user authorization, if he is having read privilege to this form, I need to set all the textbox fields to readonly.

I am actually using readonly property over disabled because, user should be allowed to use keyboard to copy the content of non-editable fields.

But now I am coming across few issues when setting the fields to readonly. When ever user clicks on backspace in the read only field, browser back functionality is getting triggered and if he clicks on space bar form location is moving to the bottom of the page.

I cannot add keydown event to bypass these backspace and spacebar keys for  all 30-40 different textboxes in Read Privilege.

Can anyone please help me resolve the same?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not set the event? Just query only the readonly inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this way, preventing backspace or space at the **focused** element that has **readonly**:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 32 && $(':focus').attr('readonly'))
 {
    alert('prevent backspace or space!');
    e.preventDefault();
 }
 else
 {
    alert('i can backspace!');
 }
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fals/0qwrj1tc/

Comment: Thanks Fals. Your suggestion helped me solve the issue. I did small modifications based on my requirement as below:                                                                  $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {        
        //8: backspace; 32: spaceBar 
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if ($(':focus').attr('readonly') && (code === 8 || code == 32)) {           
            e.preventDefault();
        }        
    });